# how to implement async function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to use async functions or promise to send data to api but

code below throws `SyntaxError: expected '=>' on the same line after an argument list, got '('`

can someone tell me what am doing wrong. here is the code

```
async createTx() {
let key = await ar.wallets.generate();

let transaction = await ar.createTransaction({
    data: '<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Hello world!</title></head><body></body></html>',
}, key);

transaction.addTag('Content-Type', 'text/html');

console.log(transaction);
alert(transaction);




    return transaction;
}

// Then call it like this:
createTx().then(result => {
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: First, the `function` is missing between `async` and `createTx`. Second, you possibly use an old runtime that doesn't recognize arrow functions yet.

Comment: As @WiktorZychla said, rewrite the very first line to `async function createTx() {`

Comment: thanks all, its working now